# NX - Github Actions - Run affected unit tests

Tags: angular, git, github-actions, nrwl-nx

I've built an NX workspace with several angular libraries and an application, which is [hosted on Github](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap) with a github workflow eg. to run on [pull requests](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/.github/workflows/pull-request.yml). At the moment workflow runs take a really long time (6 minutes) because of all the unit tests that have to be run.

```
name: pull-request

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
  
    name: pull-request
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    permissions: 
      contents: read
    
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
    
    - name: Setup node
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: 16

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install
    
    - name: Build
      run: npm run build -- --configuration=production

    - name: Test
      # run: npm run test -- --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless
      run: npm run nx affected -- --target=test --watch=false --base=remotes/origin/${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }} --head=HEAD
```

So I've been looking into running `nx affected --target=test` to only run the unit tests for which there were changes on this particular branch. According to the [documentation](https://nx.dev/concepts/affected#overview) you should be able to use the following command:

```
nx affected --target=test
```

Also, it should determine the affected files based on the branching point, and not the `HEAD` of the `master` branch

### Attempt 6

Workflow file pull-request.yml:

```
steps:
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:                     # Add this
    fetch-depth: 0          # and this

- name: Test
  run: npm run nx affected -- --target=test --watch=false --base=remotes/origin/${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }} --head=HEAD
```

This runs successfully, but it still runs all the unit tests, and not just the affected unit tests...

### EDIT 7:

Just tried using the command from @Azeem in my [workflow](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/.github/workflows/pull-request.yml#L34):

```
npm run nx affected -- --target=test --watch=false --base=${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }} --head=${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
```

which gives the [following output](https://mintplayer.com/workflow_log.txt):

```
> nx affected --target=test --watch=false --base=48c84ce3f985b00d0a61985e91c5cb5f83a94b8f --head=49253c0db3f0330f6262ff9178f0ea058b97f42f

 >  NX   Running target test for 2 projects and 9 tasks they depend on:

    - mintplayer-ng-bootstrap
    - ng-bootstrap-demo
   
   With additional flags:
     --watch=false

> nx run mintplayer-ng-animations:test  [remote cache]

No tests found, exiting with code 0

> nx run mintplayer-ng-focus-on-load:test  [remote cache]

PASS mintplayer-ng-focus-on-load libs/mintplayer-ng-focus-on-load/src/lib/directives/focus-on-load/focus-on-load.directive.spec.ts (8.812 s)
  FocusOnLoadDirective
    ✓ should focus the textbox (355 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.719 s
Ran all test suites.

PASS mintplayer-ng-qr-code libs/mintplayer-ng-qr-code/src/lib/directives/qr-code/qr-code.directive.spec.ts (9.878 s)
PASS mintplayer-ng-qr-code libs/mintplayer-ng-qr-code/src/lib/components/qr-code/qr-code.component.spec.ts

Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.352 s
Ran all test suites.

> nx run mintplayer-ng-bootstrap:test --watch=false

● Validation Warning:

  Unknown option "coverageDirectory" with value "../../coverage/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap" was found.
  This is probably a typing mistake. Fixing it will remove this message.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

PASS mintplayer-ng-bootstrap libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/toast/src/directives/toast-close/toast-close.directive.spec.ts
PASS mintplayer-ng-bootstrap libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/offcanvas/src/components/offcanvas-host/offcanvas-host.component.spec.ts
PASS mintplayer-ng-bootstrap libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/dropdown/src/dropdown-menu/dropdown-menu.directive.spec.ts
PASS mintplayer-ng-bootstrap libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/navbar/src/navbar-dropdown/navbar-dropdown.component.spec.ts
PASS mintplayer-ng-bootstrap libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/offcanvas/src/directives/offcanvas-content/offcanvas-content.directive.spec.ts
PASS mintplayer-ng-bootstrap libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/snackbar/src/component/snackbar.component.spec.ts
PASS mintplayer-ng-bootstrap libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/navbar/src/navbar-item/navbar-item.component.spec.ts
PASS mintplayer-ng-bootstrap libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/navbar/src/nav-link/nav-link.directive.spec.ts
PASS mintplayer-ng-bootstrap libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/popover/src/directives/popover/popover.directive.spec.ts
```

So I can see that the SHA-checksums are successfully pulled from the repository (`base=48c84ce3f985b00d0a61985e91c5cb5f83a94b8f` -`head=49253c0db3f0330f6262ff9178f0ea058b97f42f`)

[image: Pull request SHAs]

However, still all the unit tests are being run, for some project the command indicates `[remote cache]`

[image: remote cache]

but when there's a change in the project, CI still runs all the unit tests in the project:

[image: Unit tests are run for non-affected units]
(Unit tests are run for non-affected units)

The workflow run still takes about 7 minutes to complete, and still runs all tests.

So what am I still doing wrong here? How can I run `nx affected` to only test the files changed in my pull-request?

Comment: Did you try using SHAs instead i.e. `--base=${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }} --head=${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}`?

Comment: @Azeem Thanks, this seems to work to the extent the command that's being run contains the correct SHA-checksums. However, for some reason `nx affected` is still running all the unit tests, even though nothing's changed in the file. I updated the question with the results

Comment: Right. What about the files that you changed and what tests should be run? Do you some idea about that? Also, why are you using `fetch-depth: 0` in the checkout step? Any specific reason? Did you try removing it? Technically, it shouldn't have any effect if `--base` and `--head` are working as expected.

Comment: Also, could it be that the tests you run have such dependencies that automatically results in invoking all the tests? How about limiting it to the recent commit only? Did you try that?

Comment: Could it perhaps be because I'm using `ng-mocks` where I import the components to be mocked?

Comment: Could be. You need to verify this on your side.

Comment: Have you looked at nx graph to see how nx is understanding your projects relationships? Maybe (for some reason) it believes all projects are affected?

Comment: @GratusD. Thanks I tried it just now, and changing something does only show me the projects affected by the change. But I would expect NX to also only look at library entrypoints. My component library has several entrypoints, and making a change to only one component marks the entire project as affected, while there's 27 entrypoints which aren't affected. But I did NOT use [the NX command to generate the entrypoints](https://nx.dev/packages/angular/generators/library-secondary-entry-point)

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/olofens/nx-secondary-entrypoints-demo/blob/master/libs/example-lib/feature-a/package.json) they seem to use a `package.json` instead of an `ng-package.json`

Comment: The [NX command to generate secondary entrypoints](https://nx.dev/packages/angular/generators/library-secondary-entry-point) results in almost the same setup as I have now

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use

```
name: PRs CI
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - development
      - main

jobs:
  # check code in branch
  code-checks:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Dump Base Branch Context
        env:
          BASE_BRANCH: ${{github.base_ref}}
        run: echo "$BASE_BRANCH"

      - name: Dump Branch Context
        env:
          BRANCH: ${{github.head_ref }}
        run: echo "$BRANCH"

      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '16'
          cache: 'yarn'
      - run: corepack enable
      - run: yarn install

      - run: yarn nx format:check
      - run: "git branch --track ${{github.base_ref}} origin/${{github.base_ref}}"
      - run: "git branch --track ${{github.head_ref}} origin/${{github.head_ref}}"
      - run: yarn nx affected:lint --base=${{ github.base_ref }} --head=${{ github.head_ref }}
      - run: yarn nx affected:test --base=${{  github.base_ref }} --head=${{ github.head_ref }}
      - run: yarn nx affected:build --base=${{  github.base_ref }} --head=${{ github.head_ref }}
```